# Выделяется ли запятой "для начала"?

Tags: пунктуация

Если оборот "для начала" употребляется в значении "во-первых", должен ли он отделяться запятой, если стоит в начале предложения? Например: "Для начала, этот оборот выделяется запятой..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю так. Значения "во-первых" и "для начала" вполне могут смешиваться и заменять одно другое. Как минимум в разговорной речи.

Но коли орфография на этот счет молчит, то и следовать надо общим рекомендациям. "Для начала" обособления не требует (хотя оно, имхо, и возможно в некоторых случаях). "Во-первых" требует обособления без исключений.

//--------------

Я посмотрел обширнейший список примеров из нацкорпуса. Не могу сказать, что все проанализировал внимательно, их там полторы тысячи с хвостом, но под половину. Вывод такой. Авторы, очевидно, используют "для начала" вместо "во-первых" достаточно часто. НО: примеры не стоят того, чтобы их здесь приводить, ибо неавторитетны, и, самое главное, почти всегда возможна интерпретация "для начала" как наречия. Т.е. примеры ничего не доказывают.
Замена же на наречие возможна просто потому, что есть почти абсолютно синонимичные "сначала", "сперва". Как бы мы ни строили фразу, это "сперва" способно всегда и всюду заменить "для начала", пусть и с некоторым изменением смысла. Доказывает ли это, что "для начала" не может стать вводным в значении "во-первых"?! Не думаю.

*Я завтра собираюсь на экскурсию. - "Завтра(,) для начала(,) может пойти дождь [, а потом(,) может не быть билетов]".*  Пример мой, запятые напрашиваются, но оснований для их постановки я не могу найти.
Кто-нибудь будет уверять, что здесь "для начала" и "потом" - наречия в обычном значении, т.е. сначала дождь, а потом  - билеты? А не наоборот?

Answer (score 5):

Ну так и напишите правильно: во-первых. Зачем придумывать проблему и мучиться над ее решением?  Вариант "для начала" - явно разговорный, сомневаюсь даже в его нормативности. В устной речи запятые не нужны, а в письменной употребите более подходящий вариант.

Comment: На эту тему вспомнился анекдот.
Инспектор пишет протокол ДТП: "Туловище пострадавшего лежит на проезжей части. Голова пострадавшего лежит на тра... на тро..." - толкает ногой голову, - "...на проезжей части".
Это я про уход от проблемы.

Comment: ))))))))))))))))))))))  
Но вообще, на то наш русский язык и богат, чтобы можно было по-разному выражать свои мысли. Тем более сейчас, когда общение все чаще происходит в письменной форме. Так что, разговорная речь смешивается с письменной.

Answer (score 1):

Как объясняет "Справка" "Грамоты.ру":**ДЛЯ НАЧАЛА**,наречие, не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Comment: И я подумала, как вопрос прочитала, о том же (для начала = сначала). Но человеку именно в значении "во-первых" нужно. Видно. дальше будет продолжение...

Comment: Ларf, я ценю Ваше мнение, но здесь я не могу продолжить данное предложение, заменив "для начала" на "во-первых". Получается несуразица. Поэтому я думаю, что в качестве "во-первых" не может употребляться наречие "для начала".

Comment: "Для начала попьём чай. Потом поедим мороженое"

"Для начала надо определить проблему. Потом выбрать сотрудников для её решения. Потом спланировать время".

Comment: Спасибо за примеры. Но здесь нельзя заменить "для начала" на "во-первых, а нужен пример, где наречие "для начала" употребляется в значении "во-первых".

Comment: Почему же нельзя заменить? Даже в первом примере можно, хотя будет звучать странновато из-за смешения стилей. Но что не так во втором?

> **Во-первых**, надо определить проблему. 
> 
> **Во-вторых**, выбрать сотрудников для её решения. 
> 
> **В-третьих**, спланировать время

Comment: Для Соан: я тоже не могу. Но вопрос однозначен (если в значении "во-первых").  Поэтому я и предлагаю замену.

Comment: Всегда говорил, что отвечать надо на тот вопрос, который задан, а не тот, который хотели задать.   

>Но здесь нельзя заменить "для начала" на "во-первых"  
 
Можно. Даже если потом не будет "во-вторых", это не причина.

>Но здесь нельзя заменить "для начала" на "во-первых
Так приведите его, если он у Вас есть. заставляете гадать весь форум вместо того, чтобы дать полный контекст.

Comment: >Как объясняет "Справка" "Грамоты.ру":ДЛЯ НАЧАЛА,наречие, не требует постановки знаков препинания.   

Уважаемая @Соан, ссылка будет?! Или опять как с Лопатиным?!

А, нашел я за Вас
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_814
И вот авторы (Свинцов, Пахомов, Филатова):
http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_authors/

Справочник, кстати, весьма интересный. 
Но это опять что-неполное... У нас-то смысл другой.